# Alert Box in IE Tester

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

IE Tester has no console, and alert boxes seem to be ignored in this software.  Is this expected behavior? If so, how does one go about debugging javascript using this tool?

I have debug bar installed, but it doesn't seem to do anything useful besides allowing me to look that the DOM.

I need to be able to check the state of various objects during script execution, but I don't know how to do this without a console or alert boxes. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's a reason that hacks like IETester aren't supported-- anything that pops native UI (e.g. Alert shows a Windows MessageBox) tends to break due to DLL version mismatches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install FireBug Lite as a bookmarklet in your browsers:
http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

IE6+ support as well.

Comment: Ah yes, I always forget about firebug lite. Thanks for the reminder!!

Comment: Hi Mark,,, I want to debug javascript on ietester.. is FireBug is the solution ?

Comment: To add the Firebug bookmarklet to IETester you apparently need to launch regular Internet Explorer and add it to your favourites. It'll then show up in IETester's favourites menu (you'll need to restart it so it loads updated bookmarks). Whatever, it isn't obvious how to replace console/alert with it since its console is not available during page load :-?

Comment: If anyone comes across this answer, note that there is a problem with IETester and Firebug Lite 1.4. There is a separate SO answer that  [recommends switching to Firebug Lite 1.3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7909733/327074), which worked for me.