# How to do Internet Explorer 7 testing and javascript debugging on windows 7?

Tags: javascript, debugging, windows-7, internet-explorer-7, javascript-debugger

I have windows 7 platform and I want to test my web application on Internet explorer 7. How can I do it ?

For this I have tried various solutions. I installed ieTester for the same. It is a good tool, **but I cann't debug the javascript part in ieTester**.

One of the stackoverflow post only [Alert Box in IE Tester](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986209/alert-box-in-ie-tester)
Mark has mentioned that to use Firebug in ieTester, but I am unable to do that also.

I have also tried Microsoft expression superview in that also I havn't find any way to debug javascript.

Kindly help out in this issue.. My aim is to debug javascript on Internet Explorer 7 on windows 7 platform.

*Any successful solution of this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.*

Comment: What's wrong with firebug lite?  How is it that you are "unable to do that also"?

Comment: I am unable to get , how to use firebug lite with ieTester... :(

Comment: Just use IE 8 or 9 as Jasuten suggested... I do this(testing apps for IE versions) for a long time and never found IE developer tools insufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said above ie9 will emulate ie7 - but it is  not exactly ie7, i have seen numerous instances of real ie7 behaving differently to ie9.  What i do for this is have a virtual pc image of vista with ie7 on it.

See [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11575)

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 9 has the option to view a website in IE7 mode & has a range of debugging tools. Just press F12 to open the developer tools.

Comment: It still doesn't emulate IE7 completely in this mode.